# Listener de Firebase Firestore en Android Studio no muestra documentos actuales

Tags: android-studio, cache, firestore, listener

Tengo un SnapshotListener para escuchar una colección y actualizar los elementos en una pantalla de manera automática.

El problema es que al borrar los documentos de esa colección manualmente desde la consola, el listener no detecta estas actualizaciones, sigue trabajando con los datos que tiene en la caché, entonces la aplicación deja de funcionar, porque esos datos no existen realmente.

Adjunto código:

Aquí abro el listener:

```
db.collection("RoutesProposals").whereEqualTo("idGuide", currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).addSnapshotListener(this, (value, error) -> {
        if (value != null && !value.isEmpty() && value.getDocuments().size() > 0) {
            noRoutesAssigned.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot : value) {
                RouteProposal routeProposalAux = snapshot.toObject(RouteProposal.class);
                routesProposalsIds.add(snapshot.getId());
                routesIds.add(routeProposalAux.getRouteId());
                showNumberOfParticipantsSlashTotal(routeProposalAux.getParticipantsIds().size(), Integer.valueOf(routeProposalAux.getMaxParticipants()));
                showMainImageOfRoutes();
                datesOfRoutes.add(routeProposalAux.getWhichDay());
                db.collection("Routes").document(routeProposalAux.getRouteId()).get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                        if (document.exists()) {
                            Route routeAux = document.toObject(Route.class);
                            routesNames.add(routeAux.getName());
                            listAdapterRoutesGuide.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            noRoutesAssigned.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Actualmente no tengo ninguna colección con el nombre "RoutesProposals". No obstante, si que se detecta que la ruta existe ("value" es existe).

Esto es lo que obtengo en la consola:

**D/value: [DocumentSnapshot{key=RoutesProposals/6wNrVshqPKlrnDpe9iBQ, metadata=SnapshotMetadata{hasPendingWrites=false, isFromCache=true...}**
y luego los datos de los documentos que se encontraban dentro de la colección antes de borrarlo todo.

He probado a borrar la caché de FireStore antes de abrir el listener pero no ha funcionado.
También probé a cambiar este listener por un onCompleteListener con get() para leer solo una vez de la base de datos y sí que me lee los últimos datos que tengo. Cambié de nuevo al anterior listener para escuchar actualizaciones en tiempo real y se arregló, pero en el momento en el que borro algo de FirebaseFireStore manualmente, vuelvo a tener el mismo problema.

¿Qué es lo que me falla? ¿Cómo puedo limpiar la caché realmente? ¿O cómo obligo al SnapshotListener a escuchar directamente de la base de datos sin utilizar la caché? Esto último afectará en el rendimiento pero no se ya qué solución escoger.

Comment: En la doc, revisa el bloque de código en el apartado [**Escuchar varios documentos en una colección**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen?hl=es-419#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection) y compáralo con tu código. Tú no estás implementado escucha del evento y por eso no funciona.

Comment: @A.Cedano creo que es el mismo código pero remplazado por una expresión lambda. Una cosa que se me olvidó comentar es que este código lo implementé hace bastante tiempo, es hace un día cuando me empezó a dar problemas (supongo que por algún otro cambio que haya hecho en otra parte, pero me resulta raro).

De todas formas, con estas líneas tengo el mismo problema:

https://prnt.sc/rTxA8YE1tB1t

Comment: Pero, ¿el Log `D/value: [DocumentSnapshot{key=RoutesProposals/6w...` de dónde viene exactamente? No veo que estés haciendo Log en ninguna parte de tu código. Intenta también poner un Log para el caso de error, cosa que tampoco haces. ¿Has intentado poner puntos de interrupción, para verificar por dónde está yendo el código y qué valores tienes los objetos en cada punto?

Comment: @A.Cedano No puse en la pregunta la línea donde imprimo el Log para no emborronar el problema. El Log lo tenía puesto dentro de la comprobación de si el valor era nulo o no existía. También he puesto un Log en el caso de error y nunca se imprime. Como ya he dicho, sí que se detecta que existe un valor; lo que había dentro de la colección "RoutesProposals" antes de yo borrarla a mano en Firebase (supongo que porque lo tiene cacheado)

Comment: Firestore guardará los datos en caché si la persistencia está habilitada (es la opción por defecto), [ver la doc para más detalles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline?hl=es-419). Si no te interesa, desactiva la persistencia y no encontrarás datos en caché. Si quieres mantener la persistencia, discrimina en este contexto, para que sólo te muestre los datos con la propiedad `isFromCache=false` y listo.

Comment: @A.Cedano no había leído esa parte de la documentación y me parece muy interesante, muchas gracias!